# On the sum of the reciprocals of square roots.

Tags: real-analysis, summation

What is the analytic sum of $1+ \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{\sqrt  x}$ ?

Comment: You are replacing $k=\sqrt{x}$ in the result. What makes you think that you can do that? For example, if you would replace $k=x^2$ you get another famous series. Would that answer be consistent with your result?

Comment: It's not quite clear what your sum is. If $x=2$, what are the terms? You have $1/2$ there and then dots and then $1/\sqrt{x}$. Also, it's not clear what do you mean by "analytic sum". I assume it's a closed form for the sum, but then you talk about asymptotics. You also put equality sign in $1+\frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{k} = \log k + \gamma$, where it does not belong.

Comment: the asymptotic result is that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k - \ln n = \gamma$ or if you prefer $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k = \ln n + \gamma + \mathcal{O}(1)$

Comment: @Normal, $x$ is running over the entire set of positive integers. If $x=2$, the terms are simply $1+ \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$.

Comment: @Mathisfun Are you sure you don't have $1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+\dots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ instead?

Comment: @Imfranfat, that's why it is an attempt not a solution, which is why i'm asking anyway.

Comment: @Egreg, exactly that's what i mean, with $x$ having the floor function.

Comment: @Mathisfun So why don't you add the floor function symbol?

Comment: When you change to adding up the inverse square roots, your result is badly wrong.

Comment: Which is why i removed it @Ross

Answer (score 2):

Notice:

- $$\frac{m}{1}+\frac{m}{2}+\dots+\frac{m}{n}=m+\frac{m}{2}+\dots+\frac{m}{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{m}{k}=m\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}=m\text{H}_{n}$$
- $$m\text{H}_{n}=m\left(\psi^{(0)}(n+1)+\gamma\right)$$

So:

- $$\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\dots+\frac{1}{n}=1+\frac{1}{2}+\dots+\frac{1}{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}=\text{H}_{n}$$
- $$\text{H}_{n}=\psi^{(0)}(n+1)+\gamma$$

  ---

**EDIT**:

- $$\frac{m}{\sqrt{1}}+\frac{m}{\sqrt{2}}+\dots+\frac{m}{\sqrt{n}}=m+\frac{m}{\sqrt{2}}+\dots+\frac{m}{\sqrt{n}}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{m}{\sqrt{k}}=m\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}=m\text{H}_{n}^{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$
- $$m\text{H}_{n}^{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}=m\left(\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2},n+1\right)\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

You can approximate the sum as an integral.  It will be quite accurate if you start at a reasonably high number and use the integral above that because the square root does not change rapidly.  So if $x \gt 100$, $$\sum_{i=1}^x\frac 1{\sqrt i}\approx 18.5896+\int_{100}^x t^{-1/2}dt=18.5896+2t^{1/2}|_{100}^x=2\sqrt x-1.4104$$  t turns out starting the integral at $1$ only changes the result by $0.004$ and we get the nice result $$\sum_{i=1}^x\frac 1{\sqrt i}\approx 2\sqrt x-\sqrt 2$$

Comment: It always scares me to death when I see $i$ used as a summation variable in a context where it could well be interpreted as the imaginary unit. I *know* it is a common practice, but that only makes it worse.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: OK, I think I misunderstood your question. To confirm, your function is something like this:

```
f(100) = 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/10 (since 10 is the square root of 100)
```

Is that what you meant?

I am highly suspicious of your result.

The integral of `1/Sqrt[x]` (which can also be written `x^(-1/2)`) is `2*x^(1/2)`, a multiple of the square root function.

The Log function doesn't grow fast enough to match the square root function, so I think your result is incorrect.

Moreover, the sum: `1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + 1/5 + ... + 1/k` (no square roots) is the one that's asymptotic to ln(k).